# How to accomplish splice-like functionality over objects?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following object:

```
   var data = {
        'M.13-17': 0, 'M.18-24': 0, 'M.25-34': 0, 'M.35-44': 0, 'M.45-54': 0, 'M.55-64': 0, 'M.65+': 0,
        'F.13-17': 0, 'F.18-24': 0, 'F.25-34': 0, 'F.35-44': 0, 'F.45-54': 0, 'F.55-64': 0, 'F.65+': 0,
    };
```

I want to be able to:

1. Get first (let's say 5) properties of that object.
2. Get N properties of that object by passing `start` offset.

Currently, I have worked solution where names of object properties are implicitly specified, but I'm looking for more elegant solution.

Comment: 'get the first N properties' does not have any meaning.  Properties do not have an order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, because objects do not guarantee the order of their properties (until certain cases in ES6).

If you want stable indexes, you should use an array of key-value pairs:

```
var data = [{
  key: 'M.13-17', value: 0
}, {
  key: 'M.18-24', value: 0
}];

var firstFive = data.sort(function (it) { return it.key; }).splice(0, 5);
console.log(firstFive);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well after many hassle i can say that it can be done as converting the object into a map and then applying a slice. I believe this job will be handled easier once `Object.entries()` gets stabilized in the next ES versions but as of now you can do like...

```js
var data = {'M.13-17': 0, 'M.18-24': 0, 'M.25-34': 0, 'M.35-44': 0, 'M.45-54': 0, 'M.55-64': 0, 'M.65+': 0, 'F.13-17': 0, 'F.18-24': 0, 'F.25-34': 0, 'F.35-44': 0, 'F.45-54': 0, 'F.55-64': 0, 'F.65+': 0},
   mdata = Object.keys(data).reduce((m,k) => m.set(k, data[k]), new Map()), // convert object to map
   adata = [...mdata].splice(0,5);
   odata = adata.reduce((o,a) => {o[a[0]] = a[1]; return o} ,{})

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(odata,null,2) + "</pre>");
```

Then of course you may choose to extend the `Object.prototype` like

```js
var data = {'M.13-17': 0, 'M.18-24': 0, 'M.25-34': 0, 'M.35-44': 0, 'M.45-54': 0, 'M.55-64': 0, 'M.65+': 0, 'F.13-17': 0, 'F.18-24': 0, 'F.25-34': 0, 'F.35-44': 0, 'F.45-54': 0, 'F.55-64': 0, 'F.65+': 0};

Object.prototype.splice = function(s,e){
  var ok = Object.keys(this);
  return ok.reduce((a,k) => a.concat([[k, this[k]]]), []).splice(s, e = e || ok.length).reduce((o,a) => {o[a[0]]=a[1]; return o} ,{});
}

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(data.splice(0,5),null,2) + "</pre>");
```